# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onPress') testing

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I want to test a function that navigates to a screen. But I get this error message:

```
Test profile Page › should navigate on press

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onPress')
```

Profile.tsx

```
  if(!data) {
    function navigateToAuth(isLogin: number): void {
      isLogin === 1 ? navigation.navigate('Auth', { isLogin }) : navigation.navigate('Auth', { isLogin });
    }

    return (
      <View testID='Unlogged' style={s.container}>
        <Text style={s.title}>Login Title</Text>
        <View style={s.btnContainer}>
          <Button testID='login' onPress={() => navigateToAuth(1)} style={ButtonStyles.normal}>
            <Text style={s.btnText}>Login</Text>
          </Button>
 

        </View>  
      </View>
```

Profile_test.js

```
  it('should navigate on press', () => {
    const push = jest.fn();
    const { getByText, findByTestId } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Profile navigation={{push}} />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    )

    fireEvent.press(findByTestId('login'));
    expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Auth');
  });
```

What I am doing wrong and how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be:

```
<Profile navigation={push} />
```

with `{{push}}` you are sending undefined to navigation.

Comment: I am still getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onPress')

Comment: if you add a console.log(navigation) on the first line of the navigateToAuth function what do you see?

Comment: it works when I replace findByTestId to getByTestId